Webpack ChunkLoadError - Loading chunk X failed, even though it exist Hybrid Angular App
I was stumbled on this issue for a week .
So basically I try to install tinymce library lazyly on request. We have hybrid application angularjs & angular. I created service that lazily import tinymceNpmModule that has its own providers where i inject service that returns tinymce innstance.
When i analyze webpack i can see it is in different chunk and it works in angular solution
However I downgraded my service to be used in angularjs. so I fetch again tinymceInstance which it will load tinymce and tinymceNpmModule which is loaded but error thrown.
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk src_tinymce_components_tinymce-wrapper_tinymce-npm_module_ts failed.
(missing: https://localhost:44300/app-v2-dist/src_tinymce_components_tinymce-wrapper_tinymce-npm_module_ts.js)
at __webpack_require__.f.j (main.js?v=4dQa5wKXpQ2SyJZ_h-eKyA2:1000:28)}}

I tried to reload chunnks and hard cache reload, seems to me that is not issue in this case.
THe service is used in angularjs directive to render rte in different places, even though it works other places but in one content only it does not work.
I think it is related to timing but so far delaying process i did, not solving issue.
Can someone shed more light on this issue?
